# TableView Not Updating After todo Is Added To Array

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a todo app in Swift. But there is a problem. When someone presses the addTodo button, it adds todo to the todos array. Then I reload the tableView. But it doesn't show the new todo on screen.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputBar: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var todo : [String] = ["abc", "def", "dhe"]
      
    func reload() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData();
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell");
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    @IBAction func addTodo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if var todo = inputBar.text {
            print(todo);
            todo.append(todo)
            reload()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell;
        cell.task.text = todo[indexPath.row];
        print("Running");
        return cell;
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return todo.count;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not adding anything to the list. You are creating a new `todo` object (String) inside your `addTodo` method and then adding the same string again to it instead of adding to the data source `self.todo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very funny mistake.

In `addTodo` you append the value of the local variable `todo` to **itself** rather than to the array with the same name which is actually `self.todo`.

Name arrays always in plural form – or at least with a different name – to avoid this kind of confusion

```
var todos : [String] = ["abc", "def", "dhe"]
```

However, as the `text` property of `UITextField` is never `nil` you can simply write

```
@IBAction func addTodo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    todos.append(inputBar.text!)
    reload()
}
```

Comment: or simply don't create a string object and append the text straight to the array. `self.todo.append(inputBar.text!)`